# angular build with sourcemap but without the URL / reference

Tags: angular, webpack, source-maps, angular-webpack

I am using angular 6.

I want to debug an app in PROD, I need source map for that.
When I create a build with source map on, it injects the URL at end of minified file as

```
//# sourceMappingURL=app.min.js.map
```

This makes browser call the sourcemap and code is visible in prod.

The question is how do I make the sourcemap but don't include the URL?

I can do that as post build using gulp and other tools but is there any outofbox / simple way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that this is doable, by configuring `hidden: true` for the `sourceMap` parameter, like this:

```
"sourceMap": { "scripts": true, "styles": true, "hidden": true, "vendor": true }
```

It seems that `sourceMap` can be either a `bool` or a complex object. Please look at the [angular docs here](https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#optimization-and-source-map-configuration).

Answer (score -2):

We have to turn soureMap to 'true' in order to view and debug the .TS code with the PROD build.

In angular.json

```
"configurations": {
....
"production":{
...,
"sourceMap": true,
}
}
```

The above is working fine for me and able to debug the code.

Comment: This will include the source map enable and available to debug for everybody. I want sourcemap to be generated but reference not included in the minified filed.